# How can I remove a key from drud/ddev-ssh-agent container?

Tags: ssh, agent, ddev

I used `ddev auth ssh` to include my mainkey for projects. But accidentially a key from a diffrent customer was included into the ddev-ssh-agent container.

So how can I remove a single ssh-key.

Or how can I remove all keys to add the key I only want again.

I know, if I reboot the computer all keys are gone and I have to include them again, but is there any other way, without booting?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is there any danger in having such a key in the container? Is there any error?

Answer (score 3):

The keys are never copied into the ddev-ssh-agent container at all. It's an *agent* for the keys which remain on your host. As in Simon's other answer, you can `ddev poweroff` to turn off all ddev containers.  But it's simpler just to run `ddev auth ssh` again.

It does no harm for the ddev-ssh-agent to proxy multiple keys; that should work out just fine.

If you really want it to only handle a single key, you can put that one key in a directory by itself. For example, you could copy it to a folder named ~/.ddev-ssh-keys. Then you could set it up with the ddev-ssh-agent using `ddev auth ssh -d ~/.ddev-ssh-keys`

Answer (score 2):

You have to stop the ssh-agent container. One way is simply run `ddev poweroff` or you can use `docker rm`.